# Blink an LED on my Arduino ADK

Tags: android, sdk, arduino, adk

I'm having some problems with my Arduino [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html). I just want an app that blinks an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode). Send a signal from the app, and read in the Arduino. But I'm having some problems, like the `com.android.future.usb.accessory` library error.

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you edit your question to include the code you have so far and this library error you get - then people can see what's happening.

Comment: Which Android device are you using. Only a few Android devices are known to work with ADK.

Comment: I'm using a galaxy ace.

Comment: And Kate, i don't have too much things...i'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace imports

```
com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory;
com.android.future.usb.UsbManager;
```

to

```
android.hardware.usb.*;
```

Your code will start working. (you may need to fix some more things)